# Crear entrada en pagina principal independiente de entradas de noticias

Tags: wordpress, bucles, wordpress-theme

En mi [página principal](https://tiblioteca.com/) he cargado algunos artículos noticiosos que vamos agregando, todo por medio del loop clásico:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Ahora necesito agregar un apartado en la parte superior (por encima de las noticias y fuera de ese loop) que consiste en un artículo destacado que se añade mensualmente. El problema es que usando el mismo loop anterior no es posible ya que la publicación se incluye en la sección de noticias, y no debe ir ahí, además de que se muestra cualquier otra publicación que se va agregando.

Básicamente lo que quiero es crear una entrada independiente de las otras entradas que se publican en mi página principal.

Lo que hice al principio fue agregar este loop:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'articulo-destacado') ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Y traté de filtrarlo por la categoría `articulo-destacado`, pero no funcionó. Ojo, agregué esa entrada a través de `Entradas`, tal como agrego las noticias. Pensé que filtrandolo por la categoría podría funcionar, pero no fue así.

Otra prueba fue mediante un `custom post`, lo cual tampoco pareció funcionar. En este punto ya no se que hacer para crear una entrada en mi página principal independiente de las entradas de noticias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando el archivo index.php por defecto el loop while se conecta a los post, por ende, si quieres crear un nuevo loop debes de pasar los argumentos correctos y al finalizar el loop debes usar `wp_reset_postdata();` para evitar que afecte a otros loops, por ejemplo:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => 'ID',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        // Tu código aqui

    endwhile;

} else {

    // Tu código aqui

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

El siguiente código crea un loop que se conecta a los post, en `'cat'` se agrega el id de la categoría en caso de que quieras filtrar por categoría y en `'posts_per_page'` se agrega la cantidad de post que quieres mostrar, luego finalizas el while y lo reseteas para evitar que afecte los otros loops que tengas